# cross thread operations issue while invoking method

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, invoke, ui-thread

I'm Creating a notepad application in c# with the use of the task parallel library.But after about 2 seconds of typing I get an invalid operation exception due to cross thread calls(spellchecker) or sometimes the UI freezes as well. Could someone show me a better way to invoke my GetRichTextbox method as well. The problem I feel is somewhere on the GetRichTextBox() method.

```
public  RichTextBox GetRichTextBox()
{
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
    {
        RichTextBox rtb = null;
        TabPage tp = tabControl1.SelectedTab;
    if(tp!= null)
    {
        rtb = tp.Controls[0] as RichTextBox;
    }

    }));
    return rtb;
}



public void spellchecker()
{
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
    {       
        using (Hunspell hunspell = new Hunspell("en_us.aff", "en_US.dic"))
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(Regex.Matches(GetRichTextBox().Text, @"\w+").Cast<Match>(), match => {
                string word = match.Value;
                    Font fnt = GetRichTextBox().Font;
                    Color color;
                    if (!hunspell.Spell(word))
                    {
                        fnt = new Font(fnt.FontFamily, fnt.Size, FontStyle.Underline);
                        color = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fnt = new Font(fnt.FontFamily, fnt.Size, FontStyle.Regular);
                        color = Color.Black;
                    }

                    GetRichTextBox().Select(match.Index, match.Length); // Selecting the matching word.
                    GetRichTextBox().SelectionFont = fnt;   // Changing its font 
                    GetRichTextBox().SelectionColor = color;
                    GetRichTextBox().SelectionStart = 
  GetRichTextBox().TextLength; // Resetting the selection.
                    GetRichTextBox().SelectionLength = 0;

               });
  }
                     }));


}


 private void newtab()
{

    TabPage tp = new TabPage("New Doc");

    rtb = new RichTextBox();
    rtb.HideSelection = false;
    rtb.TextChanged += (bs, be) =>
    {
    Parallel.Invoke(
       () => spellchecker(), 
       () => wordCount());


        };
        rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        tp.Controls.Add(rtb);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);
}
```

Comment: Make the operations Async Await enabled, then you can update the Ui on main thread / Ui thread in the continuation. Cross thread issue is happening since a Ui control is getting updated on a non Ui / Thread pool therad, which is not allowed

Comment: where should I include it?

Comment: I am talking about making `spellchecker()` and `wordCount()` as async methods, no Parallel.Invoke call. Use intead Task.WhenAll to execute simultaneously and Asynchronously

Comment: Also your current code has an issue since your are accessing the `RichTextBox` object inside the Parallel loop, even when you have implemented `MethodInvoker` inside the `GetRichTextBox()`, but the challenge is then you are accessing the property `Text`, `Select`, which cause the multi threading issue, bare minimum is return values directly from Ui thread and use them, don't access RichTextBox object inside the Parallel loop

Comment: All the calls like `GetRichTextBox().Text`, `GetRichTextBox().Select` are incorrect inside the parallel loop